# Ajax Success Function not working

Tags: ajax, function

I am using Ajax to add contents on my database. And here's the code:

```
function addToFavorites(){

var recipe_id = $("#recipe_id").val();
var url = connect_url+'addFavorite.php?user_id='+user_id+'&recipe_id='+recipe_id;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: [{
        user_id: user_id,
        recipe_id: recipe_id
    }],
    url: url,
    async: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'userCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("HELLO!!!");
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("ERROR!");
    }
});

}
```

The Ajax call was successful and I was able to add records on the database but I'm just wondering why is it not displaying the alert message if the calling was successful? Is there something wrong with my code? Or is there something wrong with my understanding? Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the request is being made, but it's returning something other than a 200 back.  What does the `error` method say?  Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I edited my code above, and for the error it just displays an alert message also but neither of the two is showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must give a response with some info to the ajax or it won't know the response succeeded